# Selenium WebDriver - check if window is full screen

Tags: selenium, webdriver, fullscreen

I'm working in Groovy\Java with Selenium WebDriver. Is there a way to check if the browser window is full screen (for example if someone pressed F11)? I have tried to search for other questions on StackOverflow but I have only found ways to set fullscreen, not to check if the window is already full screen.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to suggest using a JavascriptExecutor to check the status of the [document.fullscreenElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/fullscreenElement).

```
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        WebElement fullScreen = (WebElement) js.executeScript("var element = document.fullscreenElement; return element");
```

It must be said that this does not appear to work on OSX, I always get a null back.  It may of course be specifically targeted to things like video playback.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this.

```
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    int height = size.getHeight();
    int width =  size.getWidth();
    System.out.println("height " + height + " width " + width);
```

Comment: Are you suggesting I compare the pixel size of the window to the screen resolution of my computer?

Comment: @user3804769 , Any Luck?

Comment: I'm not sure how your reply would apply to my question, sorry!

Comment: I'd recommend against this approach as it could give you a false negative if the windowed page happened to be the same size as the fullscreen page. I've seen it happen.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the page source has the `iframe` with the attribute `allowFullScreen`.